# minepy: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, regression, data-science

I am trying to use Maximal information coefficient in jupyter notebook, with the [Boston Housing dataset](https://github.com/rupakc/UCI-Data-Analysis/tree/master/Boston%20Housing%20Dataset/Boston%20Housing).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from minepy import MINE

#Read dataset
df = pd.read_csv('housing.data', delim_whitespace=True, header=None);
col_name = ['CRIM', 'ZN' , 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT', 'MEDV']
df.columns = col_name;

#Compute MIC
m = MINE()
m.compute_score(df[col_name[0:13]], df.MEDV)
print(m.mic())
```

`m.compute_score(..` is giving me a `ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)`.

#### Update

I understand now that `compute_score()` is expecting a vector instead of a matrix. What would be the proper way to find MIC scores between `df.MEDV` and the 13 features `df[col_name[0:13]]`?

Comment: Could you indicate the line number that caused the error?

Comment: @AmrKeleg I just did that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know too much about minepy but viewing the source code, `compute_score` receive `x` and `y` parameters which must be 1D arrays, then if you pass a 14xN array (2D) this wont work.

Instead `pstats` [(View on API)](http://minepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python.html#minepy.pstats) receives a 2D array and `cstats`[(View on API)](http://minepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python.html#minepy.cstats) receives a pair of 2D arrays, so you can take a look of both, as mentioned, I don't know about minepy too much or the purpose that you are looking for, but you can use them as follows:

```
from minepy import pstats, cstats

... # Load of the data

micOneVector, ticOneVector = pstats(df)            # Returns mic and tic (Arrays of 1D)

micTwoVectors, ticTwoVectors = cstats(df, df.MEDV) # Returns mic and tic (Arrays of 1D)
```

References

[minepy - Source code](https://github.com/minepy/minepy/blob/master/minepy/mine.pyx)

[minepy - Python API](http://minepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python.html)

Comment: I think this might be the answer. I am yet to try it. However, it seems `cstats()` is the more appropriate function, since in my example it's not a pairwise statistic. Can you kindly update your answer so that I can accept it. Thx! http://minepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python.html#convenience-functions-example